# JSplitPane analogue for Delphi

Tags: delphi, splitter

Can someone point to good delphi component that is an analogue for java JSplitPane.
I know about standard TSplitter in Delphi, but I sick and tied of using it.

Comment: What sort of problems are you having with TSplitter?

Comment: Hm... wonder how can somebody get "tired" of using a simple TSplitter...

Comment: If you have multiple controls with the same alignment as the splitter (say 3 alLeft), and the splitter resizes the control down to 0 width, it can mess up control ordering and start resizing the wrong control.

Comment: Mason Wheeler, my problem is that TSplitter very often behaves unpredictable. If you google around you can find examples.
And most of all - TSplitter is not a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Raize components](http://www.raize.com/devtools/rzcomps/componentlist.asp) has a nifty splitter: it consists of two panes (that can host other controls) and the splitter in the middle.

Comment: This is how any spiltter should bee!

Comment: (Wow, that was enough spelling errors for one small comment!)

Comment: Vegas, use spell checker :)
Opera 10.10 and Firefox (not sure) have one :)

Answer (score 3):

The [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) components comes with 4 splitters.

[image]

- TJvSplitter
- TJvxSplitter
- TJvSyncSplitter
- **TJvNetscapeSplitter**  (This is very similar (visually) to JSplitPane)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Plasmatech splitter in their Shell Control Pack, and like it.
http://plasmatech.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look for it